# c# Ternary operator returning different types

Tags: c#-4.0, ternary-operator

I'm trying to use the ternary to return differing types, although I seem to be encountering some problems.  My question is can the ternary operator not return differing types?

```
// This line causes an error
propertyGrid.Instance = (directoryRecord.directoryInfo != null) 
    ? directoryRecord.directoryInfo 
    : directoryRecord.fileInfo;

// Compiles fine
propertyGrid.Instance = directoryRecord.directoryInfo;

// Compiles fine
propertyGrid.Instance = directoryRecord.fileInfo;
```

Error

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is
>   no implicit conversion between 'System.IO.DirectoryInfo' and
>   'System.IO.FileInfo'

Comment: aside: it's the conditional operator (ternary operator is a set of operators that take three arguments of which only one exist in C#)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, this doesn't work like that.
The expression of a *conditional operator* has a specific type. Both types used in the expression must be of the same type or implicitly convertible to each other.

You can make it work like this:

```
propertyGrid.Instance = (directoryRecord.directoryInfo != null) 
    ? (object)directoryRecord.directoryInfo 
    : (object)directoryRecord.fileInfo;
```

Comment: doesn't need to be castable. Implcitly convertible will also do

Comment: @RuneFS: Thanks, that's what I meant. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

No.
Both return values ultimately need to be stored in the same single variable that will hold the result.
So the compiler has to have a way of deciding the type of that variable / storage area.
Because of the language type safety you have to know the type, and they are both gonna end up in the same variable.