# Assign nullable int to int in ternary operator

Tags: c#, nullable

I have a `class` say

```
class Test
{
   int? a;
   int b;
}
```

Now i m creating a object of `test class`

```
Test objTest = new Test();
objTest.b = objTest.a;
```

Here it throws error `cannot  implicitly convert int? to int`.

So i came up with solution

```
objTest.b  = ObjTest.a ?? 0;
```

Works fine Here But !!!

```
objTest.b = objTest.a == null ? 0 : objTest.a
```

Fails ..

Why basically both doing the same `checking null value and assign value accordingly`

Comment: The actual question is _"What is the type of the conditional operator?"_, which has been answered before. See [Conditional operator assignment with Nullable<value> types?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75746/), [Nullable type issue with ?: Conditional Operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295833/), [In C# why can't a conditional operator implicitly cast to a nullable type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220250/), [c# Ternary operator returning different types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12894911/) and so on. Instead of "fails" explain what happens and research that.

Comment: `Object.a.Value` will pass.

Comment: see that method=> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72cec0e0(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You would still need to cast `a` to an int in your second example.

```
objTest.b = objTest.a == null ? 0 : (int)objTest.a
```

will compile. But just do it the first way you came up with.

Comment: Instead of a cast, i'd suggest the .Value property on the Nullable<int>